# proving that a group G has in order equal to a power of 2

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I was working on a finite group $G$ in which every element different from the identity element has an order of $2$, and my goal is to prove that $|G|=2^r,r\in\mathbb{N}$. I did find a proof and I want to know whether it is true or not.

Used lemma:

- for every subgroup $H\neq G$,$\forall a\in G\backslash H,K=H\cup aH$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $2|H|$

My attempt:
Let $n$ be the order of $G$, Let $(a_k)_{k\in\{{0,..,n-1}\}}$ the elements of $G$, with $a_0$ the identity element.
Let $(H_k)_{k\in\{{0,..,n-1}\}}$ defined in the following way:

- $H_0=\{a_0\}$
- for $k\in\mathbb\{0,..,n-2\}$: $H_{k+1}=H_k\cup a_{k+1}H_k$.

I will prove by induction that $\forall k\in\{0,..,n-1\},\forall p\in\{0,..,k\},a_p\in H_k$

- Base Case $(k=0):\ $we have $a_0\in H_0\implies\forall p\in\{0,..,k\},a_p\in H_k$
- Let $k\in \{0,..,n-2\}/\forall p\in\{0,..,k\},a_p\in H_k$, we have
  $$ H_k\subset H_{k+1} \text{ and }a_{k+1}\in H_k \text{ from the definition of } (H_k)
  \\ \implies \forall p\in\{0,..,k+1\},a_p\in H_{k+1}
  $$
  Hence our result is proved, we can deduce that $|H_{n-1}|\ge n\implies |H_{n-1}|\ge|G|$

Now I will prove (by induction again) that : $\forall k\in\{0,..,n-1\} \ H_k$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $\exists r \in \mathbb{N}/|H_k|=2^r$

- Base Case: $H_0$ is a (trivial) subgroup of $G$ and $|H_0|=2^0$
- Let $k\in \{0,..,n-2\}/ \ H_k$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $\exists r \in \mathbb{N}/|H_k|=2^r: \ $

if $a_{k+1} \in H_k$, then:
$$ a_{k+1}H_k=H_k \text{ since } H_k \text{ is a group} \implies H_{k+1}=H_k$$
Otherwise, by our lemma, we have $H_{k+1}$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $2|H_k|=2^{r+1}$.

In both cases, $H_{k+1}$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $\exists r \in \mathbb{N}/|H_{k+1}|=2^r$.

So this result is also proved, and we can deduce that $H_{n-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $|H_{n-1}|=2^r,r\in \mathbb{N}$, So $H_{n-1}\subset G$, but $|H_{n-1}|\ge |G|\implies H_{n-1}=G$

Conclusion:
$$|G|=n=2^r,r\in\mathbb{N}$$

So that was my proof, and my main concern here is the validity of this form of induction (and my proof in general), and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

By [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) if the order of the group were divisible by an odd prime $p$ it would have an element of order $p$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I writed my answer, I was not aware of this theorem, and of course what I am trying to prove is an immediate result of it. Anyways can you verify my method?

Comment: Not sure I follow your method.  It's obvious, by construction, that $p≤k\implies a_p\in H_k$, no?

Comment: If your argument is that $G=H_k$ for some $k$ and the order of each of the $H_k$ is a power of $2$, then I agree with you.  I still advise looking up the proof of Cauchy's Theorem.  It's much more general and not significantly harder to prove.

Comment: yeah that's my argument, and yes it's obvious by construction, but this is my first year in abstract algebra, so I was advised to write proofs with rigour until being used with such new notions

Comment: Ok, then I think this is clear.  Like I say, I'd have omitted your first inductive step (as I consider it obvious from the construction) but if your goal is to include all the details it does no harm to include it.